# Error using unsigned int bit-field struct in C

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

I am using `struct` with `unsigned int` bit-fields perfectly, but suddenly, after duplicating one of them, the compiler is losing its mind (it would seem). Here's my code:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
    unsigned int myVar:1;
} myStruct; // my compiler requires TWO declarations of the name for typedef

myStruct myNewStructVar;

myNewStructVar.myVar = 0; // throws error that "myNewStructVar" is unknown to the compiler
```

What gives? Again, I have two versions of this EXACT thing and it works fine.

Comment: Your code works fine in MSVS2010. what your compiler?

Comment: C89 for a microchip, same error in Xcode using the C89. Xcode throws "unknown type name" error.

Comment: So maybe someone can answer this, it wasn't allowing me to do this in the variable declaration area OUTSIDE of a method. However, inside a method it worked fine. Geesh!

Comment: "method"?  Are you speaking C, C++ or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I'm doing C not C++. It's standard to not assign values outside of a method using dot notation. I'm spoiled by ++. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the variable as a global outside of function scope, but you can't have a separate line of code to set its value. Setting the value on a separate line is executable code rather than initialization, and is not permitted there.

If you want to initialize it at the point of declaration, try:

```
myStruct myNewStructVar = {0};
```

This should work where it is now.